# Why in JavaFX ReadOnlyXPropety implements ObservableValue interface

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to understand JavaFX property API and noticed that ReadOnlyBooleanProperty, and ReadOnlyStringProperty and other ReadOnlyXPropety classes implement ObservableValue interface. Why do we need change listeners on read only properties? Or I don't understand something...

Comment: where's the problem? ObservableValue has a addListener(changeListener) ..

Comment: “ReadOnly” does not mean the value never changes, it just means no one other than the owning class can cause it to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A read-only property does not necessarily mean that the value of that property will never change, it just means it can't be *externally* changed.

An example of this is the [`Worker`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Worker.html) interface and its abstract implementations, such as [`Task`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html). A `Worker` has various read-only properties including: `title`, `message`, `progress`, `value`, etc. These properties are meant to convey information about the `Task`'s progress to the UI. With that in mind, it makes no sense to allow these properties to be modified from an outside source. But it must still provide a way to modify these properties from the background task. In `Task`, this is done via the protected `updateMessage`, `updateProgress`, and other methods.

Internally, this is accomplished by using the `ReadOnlyXXXWrapper` classes. These implementations extend their corresponding `SimpleXXXProperty` classes but expose a specialized `ReadOnlyXXXProperty` that is *truly* read-only. By "truly", I mean it doesn't implement [`WritableValue`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/value/WritableValue.html). This looks something like:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private final ReadOnlyStringWrapper message = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(this, "message");

    private void setMessage(String message) {
         this.message.set(message); 
    }

    public final String getMessage() { 
        return message.get(); 
    }

    public final ReadOnlyStringProperty messageProperty() {
        return message.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

}
```

Note that the setter only allows the class itself to change the property. To the rest of the world, the property is completely read-only.

Answer (score 1):

The `ReadOnlyProperty` class is only a wrapper which can be exposed as (literly) readonly. In the back a value might still change.

Look at the `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper` for examples. They are often used privatly for value changing, while the property returned from `ReadOnlyPropertyWrapper#getReadOnlyProperty()` is used for exposing the `ObservableProperty` as readonly.